# Wordpress plugin losing formatting on post

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the Frontier Post plugin, which does not seem to have active support.

I am running into the problem that when I edit and save a post through the front end, which is one of the features of this plugin, the post somehow loses its formatting. e.g. if I had three paragraphs of text, it becomes one large paragraph, even though when I "inspect" it on chrome, one can clearly see the line breaks.

Why  would the text be displaying with no paragraph breaks, even though the inspect code contains them? Perhaps I could fix this with CSS?

Comment: Are the line breaks part of the text or are they created through `<p>...</p>` or `<br>` tags. If the line breaks are just new line or carriage return characters then showing it as a single paragraph is correct formatting.

Comment: On the inspect page on chrome, they are just line breaks in the text. If I want to edit the post as text, they are <!-- wp:paragraph -->

Comment: For browsers to render text in paragraph blocks, each paragraph needs to be within `<p>...</p>` tags (or have line breaks delineated by `<br>`). From the sounds of it you are using WordPress Gutenberg, which uses `<!-- wp:paragraph -->` in its editor to delineate paragraphs, which are then rendered into `<p>` tags in the frontend. If they aren't getting rendered into `<p>` tags I'd guess that the Frontier Post plugin hasn't been updated to work with Gutenberg, so is losing such formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much, your response is very helpful. Do you know of any instructionals online that could help me update the plugin so that it is compatible with Wordpress Gutenberg?

Comment: A quick glance through the Frontier Post plugin's gitlab shows that it's not a small or simple plugin, so updating to work properly with Gutenberg would likely be quite an undertaking! If it doesn't break the rest of your site, perhaps installing the Classic Editor plugin to revert the WordPress editor to pre-Gutenberg would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem is only occurring when I create a post in the back end, and try to edit it in the front end. A post created through the front end does not have this issue.

The problem is due to the fact that Frontier Post has not been updated in a while, and is therefore not compatible with Wordpress Gutenberg. Wordpress Gutenberg (used when creating a post through the back end) uses `<!-- wp:paragraph -->` to delineate new lines.

Therefore, when a post is edited in the front end, by Frontier Post, it does not recognize `<!-- wp:paragraph -->` as a new line,

.

Since it won't affect the users of my site, I just decided to leave things as they are and make sure that my posts are properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not enough reputation to comment, however I was wondering if you had enough line breaks?

Just having one `<br />` would only push the text to the next line, it wouldn't create a separate "paragraph."

Either put in two `<br />` tags or split the paragraphs into `<p>` tags and add css from there (Which is probably the better option)

Comment: Thank you for our answer! If I use <p> tags, what css should I add from there?

Comment: I think the `<p>` tags will automatically space out your text. If not, try adding classes to them like:

    <p class="myparagraph">
        ... Paragraph 1 content ...
    </p>
    <p class="myparagraph">
        ... Paragraph 2 content ...
    </p>

And then in your css:
    .myparagraph {
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
    }